# Elasticsearch Marvel not collecting Windows OS stats

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I'm running a 3 node Elasticsearch cluster on Windows 2012 servers. I have another single Windows 2012 server that is the Marvel server. I have added the Marvel plugin to all Elasticsearch instances and set the appropriate settings in the Elasticsearch config for the Marvel agent.

I get most data into Marvel apart from what looks like OS stats. Looking at the logs from the elasticsearch instance on the Marvel server, the following exception is logged:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.facet.FacetPhaseExecutionException: Facet [0]: (value) field [os.load_average.1m] not found
```

Wondering if this is a known issue or anyone else had a similar problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Elasticsearch consultant @DavidPilato, its a known issue with the Windows JVM.

> Sadly Windows JVM does not expose all needed data to Marvel (and to our Node Stats API BTW).

Hope this helps clarify the issue with anyone else running Elasticsearch on Windows JVM.